# Trouble with Bean-IO, XML Doctype, and XSD

Tags: java, xsd, bean-io

I am using a toolkit called 'beanio' to parse a fixed length flat file in Java.  With the toolkit I am required to define the file format with an XML document.  I can refer to the schema location on the beanio website, but i'd much rather use a local copy.  The reason is that I want to be sure that in case anything happens to the site, I will have a working program.

My problem is that when I try to reference the xsd file locally, the SAX engine throws an error about malformed xml / definitions.  The following will work:

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">
```

However, the following will not:

```
<!DOCTYPE beanio SYSTEM "resources/formatting/mapping.xsd">
<beanio>
```

These files, mapping.xsd, whether referenced locally or on the internet are *exactly the same*.

The error thrown is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/workspace/LookupsFileProcessor/resources/formatting/mapping.xsd; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 2; The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

This has been extremely frustrating.  The toolkits for flat file parsing for java are very old and out dated.  I have tried FOUR of them and some either don't have a usable API or they rely on external DTD/XSD definitions which cause me to run into this same exact issue.

I understand XML well enough, or so I thought, and I am not sure what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well boy do I feel ridiculous.  So the method of formatting using a DTD is specified using a doctype declaration.  In my example I am actually using XSD to do my XML formatting which is a *different technology* than DTD.

The correct way to specify a local XSD file using the XML Schema method is simply as follows:

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 resources/formatting/mapping.xsd">
```

I hope I can help anyone else from looking foolish.  Thanks!